# Looping rolling average in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to make a smoothing function via looping rolling average, in SQL. My current code for a non-looping method looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE #Input ( 
         PartitionID  int
       , TimeID     int
       , Quantity float );

INSERT INTO #Input
  VALUES
   ( 1, 1, 2 ),
   ( 1, 2, 4 ),
   ( 1, 3, 6 ),
   ( 1, 4, 16 ),
   ( 2, 4, 6 ),
   ( 2, 5, 1 ),
   ( 2, 6, 9 ),
   ( 2, 7, 2 );

SELECT *
  FROM #Input;

-- Actual code
UPDATE i
  SET i.Quantity = i2.c
  FROM #Input i
       JOIN ( SELECT PartitionID AS a
                   , TimeID AS b
                   , AVG(Quantity) OVER(Partition BY PartitionID ORDER BY TimeID ASC ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS c
                FROM #Input
            ) i2
               ON i2.a = i.PartitionID
                  AND i2.b = i.TimeID;
-- /Actual code

SELECT *
  FROM #Input;
```

I would like to make this loop, so that the first row of each partition references the last row and vice-verse. Any thoughts?

EDIT:
The desired output would be:

```
1    1    7.33
1    2    4
1    3    8.66
1    4    8
2    4    3
2    5    5.33
2    6    4
2    7    5.66
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Please edit the tags.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @stickybit I'm... not sure. I think we use Transact-SQL, but database management isn't really my forte.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sample data is included in the code. I've added a desired output.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a very interesting question. What I do is try to expand the original table by adding two rows for each PartitionID group, one with max(TimeID)+1 and another with min(TimeID)-1, while the [Quantity] value is just the opposite.
For example, for PartitionID = 1, I will add two rows to make the original four rows into six rows as follows (the 1st and last two rows are added)

```
( 1, 0, 16 )  
( 1, 1, 2 ),
( 1, 2, 4 ),
( 1, 3, 6 ),
( 1, 4, 16 ),
( 1, 5, 2 )
```

The whole query is as follows:

```
--drop table #input;
CREATE TABLE #Input ( 
         PartitionID  int
       , TimeID     int
       , Quantity float );

INSERT INTO #Input
  VALUES[![enter image description here][1]][1]
   ( 1, 1, 2 ),
   ( 1, 2, 4 ),
   ( 1, 3, 6 ),
   ( 1, 4, 16 ),
   ( 2, 4, 6 ),
   ( 2, 5, 1 ),
   ( 2, 6, 9 ),
   ( 2, 7, 2 );

select * from #Input;

   ; with c as (
                select partitionid, min_timeid = min(timeid), max_timeid = max(timeid)
                from #Input
                group by partitionid
               )
, c2 as (
            select c.PartitionID, TimeID= c.max_timeid+c.min_timeid-i.TimeID + case i.TimeID when c.max_timeid then -1 else 1 end , i.Quantity
            from c
            inner join #input i
            on c.partitionid = i.PartitionID
            and i.TimeID in (c.max_timeid, c.min_timeid)
            union
            select * from #Input
)
update i 
set i.Quantity = i2.c
from #Input i
inner join ( SELECT PartitionID AS a
                   , TimeID AS b
                   , AVG(Quantity) OVER(Partition BY PartitionID ORDER BY TimeID ASC ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS c
                FROM c2
            ) i2
               ON i2.a = i.PartitionID
                  AND i2.b = i.TimeID;

SELECT * from #input;
```

The final result is

[image]

Comment: That was my thought as well, though I wasn't sure how best to implement it. Can this method be generalized if the width of the averaging is arbitrary? I guess the line:
    and i.TimeID in (c.max_timeid, c.min_timeid)
would have to become something like:
    and i.TimeID between c.max_timeid-@radius and c.max_timeid or bewteen c.min_timeid and c.min_timeid+radius)

Also, this method assumes the TimeIDs contiguous. If possible, I would prefer to only require that they by sequential

Comment: @Sinnombre, not quite understand your comment. But one thing I'd correct you, for the solution, there is NO assumption that TimeID should be continuous.

Comment: You're right, I was looking at the hard coded '1' and '-1' in the c2 select statement, but of course given that they apply to max and min they won't care about continuity. My other question was about changing the width of the averaging, as in, averaging over 5 points, or 7 points, or some other arbitrary number not known until runtime. Can this method be generalized to account for that without using for loops?

Comment: Yes, this solution can be generalized over 2N+1 points (where N is 1, 2, 3,....). If you modify your question (with sample data of course), I can modify my solution to make it generalized. :-)